# Inspecting HTTP requests made by gcloud utility

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud

I am calling various sub-commands using `gcloud` utility with `--log-http` flag to see the details about HTTP request being made to Google Cloud API.

In the output, I can see the request URL, headers and request body.

However, the value for authentication header is displayed as:

```
--- Token Redacted ---
```

Is there a way I could make `gcloud` utility output the authentication token too?

Comment: AFAIK no. The token used is the same one generated by `gcloud auth print-access-token`. Is there a reason you need the actual token? Note: you have the source code to the `gcloud` tool as it is written in Python. You could modify the code yourself to not redact the token.